# Questions held for being opinion based

Tags: support

[I just posed a question in causal set notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253515/causal-set-notation-round-brackets-vs-square-brackets) (in general relativity), referencing papers 50 years old and 5 years old, seeking to know whether notation has changed or usage is a matter of personal preference.

This question has been put on hold as being "primarily opinion-based".

However, what I want to know is the *fact* of whether it is a matter of opinion or whether there is some authority or consensus for one form or another; I am writing a paper intended for submission and need to be correct in my notation if I am to avoid avoidable referee objections.

I also can't see how to discuss this with the admin who put it on hold.

How are such questions to be managed when, as in this case, the asker acknowledges that the answer may involve discussion of matters of opinion but is not seeking opinions about opinions (if they are such) but facts about them.

(Getting rather more meta than I would like, but I can't see how to avoid it!)

Question is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253515/causal-set-notation-round-brackets-vs-square-brackets?noredirect=1#comment559239_253515)

Comment: Firstly, thanks for airing your grievance here at meta. Please cite the link of the specific question here. I've seen that question. If you want to contact him, come at [The h bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar); ping hime about your query. He would surely response.

Comment: Relevant meta post: [Are physics-related notation and terminology questions on-topic?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/50583)

Comment: Quick note: the nature of this site is that you don't have to get a question taken off hold by the same person who put it on hold. So there's no particular reason you have to get in contact with the person or people who originally put the question on hold. If it deserves to have the hold removed, other people can just as well carry that out.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Wouldn't have called it a grievance - sounds as though I'm offended, which I'm not - just in a bit of a Catch-22 situation :) Hope the hold gets lifted.

Comment: Hi Julian Moore, sorry to keep you waiting, but I have other matters to attend to. What David Z said above.

Comment: @Qmechanic - no worries, no SLA AFAIK  here :) ocelo7 has given me "authorities" for () over [] so it's answered without even being asked, sort of. Thanks to all for input.

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question. (It takes 5 votes to do so.) I'd rather like to see more questions like this here.